# Pull request for a branch contains commits from other branches

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

Say I have two branches, `master` and `dev`.

I created a branch from `master`, made changes and merged to `master`.

Now I created another branch from `master`, but pushed my changes to `dev` and am trying to merge them, but when I make the pull request, the first branch merged to `master` appears in my request. How can I avoid this?

(The problem is that I should have merged the first branch to `dev` not `master` but now I can't do that anymore, because the same changes were merged to `dev` with another, third branch.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note: if this is TL;DR, skip down to the last section, *Drawing your pull request*.**

Let's draw what you already did.  Remember, in Git, each commit "points back" to its *parent* commit, or for a *merge commit*, to both of its (two) parents; and a branch name like `master` or `dev` or `newbranch` simply points to *one* commit, with the commits themselves doing the pointing-back so as to represent a whole series of commits.

I have to make some assumptions here.  Bitbucket (which I have not used since they converted from a Mercurial-only shop to Git) and GitHub (which I do use) are a little bit different, but since they both use Git underneath, have a lot of similarities.  I am going to assume you're using what Bitbucket's web site calls a "forking workflow".

I am going to try to avoid making many other assumptions.  That makes this answer very long and complicated.  (It might have served you well to have provided more information in your question, so that the answer could be shorter.)

#### Drawing what you have, part 1

So, you started with:

```
... <-B <-C <-D   <-- master
```

where commit `D` points back to commit `C`, `C` points back to `B`, and so on, and `master` points to `D`.  Note that each of these single uppercase letters stands in for an actual commit hash ID, one of those incomprehensible `1badc0ffee4deadcab...` or whatever things.  We use the letters here because they're simple and easy and comprehensible; Git uses the hashes because the letters run out after just 26 commits. :-)  (And for other better reasons.)

We know commits always point backwards.  They *have to:* you can't point forwards to a commit you haven't made yet!  So let's not bother with the interior arrows.  But the branch names move over time, so let's keep drawing *their* arrows:

```
...--B--C--D   <-- master
```

Now you created a *new* branch, which also points to `D`:

```
...--B--C--D   <-- master, newbranch (HEAD)
```

(Here's a quick exercise for you: which of these three commits are on `master`, and which are on `newbranch`?  This is a little bit of a trick question, because the answer is that all three commits are on *both* branches.)

We've added this `HEAD` notation so that we can tell *which* branch you're "on", as in, `git status` says `on branch newbranch`.  Now you make a new commit `E`.  Git makes the *current* branch—the one marked `HEAD`—point to the new commit we just made, and has the new commit point back to the previous branch-tip:

```
...--B--C--D   <-- master
            \
             E   <-- newbranch (HEAD)
```

Let's make two more commits just for the heck of it:

```
...--B--C--D   <-- master
            \
             E--F--G   <-- newbranch (HEAD)
```

Now the name `newbranch` points to `G`, which points back to `F`, and so on.

#### Drawing what you have, part 2: merging `newbranch`

The next part is tricky.  You did:

```
git checkout master; git merge newbranch
```

or maybe:

```
git checkout master; git merge --no-ff newbranch
```

but you don't say *which of these you did.*  The `git checkout` will make the `HEAD` label attach to `master`.  But, given the drawing we've drawn here, you can see that Git could just slide the name `master` forward, in the left-to-right direction that is the opposite of all the internal arrows in the branches, so that the name `master` points to `G`:

```
...--B--C--D
            \
             E--F--G   <-- master (HEAD), newbranch
```

Git calls this label-sliding operation a *fast-forward*.  One critical thing about this is that a fast-forward operation *does not make a merge commit*.  This makes it harder to see where `master` was before you ran `git merge`, because we can straighten out the kink in the drawing and get:

```
...--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- master (HEAD), newbranch
```

Given that `D` is really `4384e3cde2ce8ecd194202e171ae16333d241326` or some such big ugly hash ID, you probably don't remember what it really was.  How will you know that you merged exactly three commits, and that `master` used to be `4384e3cde2ce8ecd194202e171ae16333d241326`?

You can use the `--no-ff` kind of merge to *force* Git to make a real merge even if it otherwise doesn't have to.  This helps figure out what happened.  Instead of just sliding the *name* `master` forward, Git will do this:

```
...--B--C--D---------H   <-- master (HEAD)
            \       /
             E--F--G   <-- newbranch
```

In other words, here Git makes a new *merge commit* `H`.  The new commit points back to *both* `D` *and* `G`.  This is in fact what makes it a merge commit: it points to two parents.

#### Why we're doing all this graph-drawing

The precise shape of the post-`git merge`-command graph doesn't affect your current problem.  You would get this same thing with either of the two post-merge graphs.  Still, it's important to note when merge commits go in, and what they do: they record this kind of actual history, for future exploration.  And in either case, it's important to be *able* to draw the graph, to predict what will happen with a pull request.  Both post-`merge`-command graphs result in a problem.

Sometimes, making this "merge bubble" commit `H` pointing back to both `G` *and* `D`* is just useless clutter.  If there's no future need to remember that this group of commits came in all at once via merging, you can and probably should use the fast-forward merge.  If you want to force a real merge, you now know that there is this `--no-ff` option to `git merge` to do that.

If you use GitHub to make merges (perhaps via pull requests), you can use GitHub's controls to decide whether to force real merges.  These controls are different from Git's (naturally, as they are GUI clicky buttons in your browser).  GitHub generally tries to hide these graphs from you, which I think is a mistake—the graph is crucial in determining what is actually possible and what will happen when you try various things.  For instance, it shows, visually, *why* your pull request had the problem.

(I have not used Bitbucket's web interface but I assume it works much like GitHub's.)

#### Drawing your second set of changes

You now say:

> Now I created another branch from `master`, but pushed my changes to `dev` and am trying to merge them, but when I make the pull request, that first branch merged to `master` appears in my request.

Let's assume you made a fast-forward merge and therefore have this in your Git repositories, to start with.  I'll assume you've deleted `newbranch` or that we don't care about it, and that your *new* new branch, which you "pushed to `dev`", is called `zaphod`:

```
...--D--E--F--G   <-- master, zaphod (HEAD)
```

Now you make a few new commits (let's put in two):

```
...--D--E--F--G   <-- master
               \
                H--I   <-- zaphod (HEAD)
```

You then do something—it's not clear to me precisely what series of Git commands and/or Web and/or GUI clicky boxes—to get your *Bitbucket* repository to make the name `dev` also refer to commit `I`, or perhaps to a new merge commit `J` that points back to `I`.

Note that there are *two* Git repositories of your own involved at this point: one on your local computer, and one on Bitbucket.  The interesting thing about Git hash IDs, which we've been drawing here as single uppercase letters, is that they are *the same* in all copies of every repository.  (This is *not* true of branch names!)  So over on Bitbucket, instead of `zaphod`, we have the name `dev` pointing to commit `J`.  We also don't really need the `HEAD` notation since you don't commit directly on Bitbucket:

```
...--D--E--F--G   <-- master
               \
                H--I   <-- dev
```

Meanwhile, there's a *third* repository that we need to bring in.  This third repository is the one you forked from, in your Bitbucket "forking workflow".

I will assume for the moment that this third repository started out looking like this:

```
...--B--C--D   <-- master, dev
```

(If this is not the case, it's your job to draw the appropriate portions of the graph that they *do* have in this third repository.)

#### Drawing your pull request

With all the above out of the way, let's look at what a pull request really is.

All that a pull request *is*, is a request (hence the name) that *someone else* add, to their repository, some set of commits from one of *your* repositories, using a name associated with your particular repository—such as your `dev`—and a name associated with *their* repository, often the same name again.

In this case, the repository you make the pull request *from* is the one you have stored on Bitbucket that is your fork of their repository.  So that's why we need the drawing of the graph that's in your Bitbucket repository:

```
...--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- master
                     \
                      H--I   <-- dev
```

We also need to know what they have in *their* repository.  I've assumed this:

```
...--B--C--D   <-- master, dev
```

***Note that your `D` and their `D` are literally the same commit.***

What you are asking them to do is to set *their* `dev` to point to commit `I`.

For them to do that, they must take *your* commits `E--F--G--H--I` into their repository, resulting in:

```
...--B--C--D   <-- master
            \
             E--F--G--H--I   <-- dev
```

But that's not what you really want them to do right now.  You want them to take some commit(s) that *somewhat resemble* `H` and `I`, and do this:

```
...--B--C--D   <-- master
            \
             H2--I2   <-- dev
```

To get that to happen, *you must first make `H2` and `I2` yourself.*

To make `H2` and `I2`, you will need to *copy* your original commits `H` and `I` to new commits.  You will need these new commits to come right after commit `D`.  So now you need to locate *their* tip-of-`dev` commit.

I've been drawing this as commit `D`, but that might not be correct.  I don't have your repositories and have had to make various guesses (including your chosen Bitbucket workflow).

If you have their Bitbucket repository set up as an *upstream*, you can run `git fetch remote-name` to get your own Git, on your local computer, to obtain their latest commit from their `dev` and record it as `remote-name/dev`.  (Typically *your* Bitbucket fork would be named `origin`, so that `origin/dev` records *your* fork's `dev` in your repository on Bitbucket.  You might name *their* Bitbucket repository `upstream` so that `upstream/dev` names the commit at the tip of their `dev` branch.)

Let's say, for concreteness, that *their* Bitbucket repository, which you can refer to by the name `upstream` from your local Git repository, actually has this in it:

```
...--B--C--D   <-- master
            \
             N--O   <-- dev
```

Here you'd run `git fetch upstream`, and now *your* repository—your local one, not your copy on Bitbucket yet—would have:

```
                      H--I   <-- zaphod (HEAD), origin/dev
                     /
...--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- master
            \
             N--O   <-- upstream/dev
```

You then need to create your own branch that points to commit `O`.  To do that locally, you can use `git checkout` with `-b` and `--track`:

```
$ git checkout -b for-upstream-dev --track upstream/dev

                      H--I   <-- zaphod, origin/dev
                     /
...--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- master
            \
             N--O   <-- upstream/dev, for-upstream-dev (HEAD)
```

Now you can copy commits `H` and `I` to commits `H2` and `I2`, using `git cherry-pick`:

```
 $ git cherry-pick zaphod~2..zaphod

                      H--I   <-- zaphod, origin/dev
                     /
...--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- master
            \
             N--O   <-- upstream/dev
                 \
                  H2--I2   <-- for-upstream-dev (HEAD)
```

Once you have this set up in your *local* repository, you need to get *your* Bitbucket repository to set *its* `dev` to point to commit `I2`.  To do that you must force-push.  Normally, force-pushing is bad, as it tells another Git repository to *lose* some commits, but here you *want* your Bitbucket repository to lose its `H--I` commits.  So:

```
$ git push --force origin for-upstream-dev:dev
```

would have your (local) Git call up the `origin` Git—that's *your* Bitbucket Git—and tell it: *I give you my `I2`, and of course my `H2` and `O` and `N` if you need them; now you set your `dev` to my `I2`!*

Assuming they obey this command, Bitbucket will now change its copy of your fork to look like this:

```
...--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- master
            \
             N--O--H2--I2   <-- dev
```

(And, when the `origin` Git accepts this push, your own Git moves your `origin/dev` to point to `I2`, to remember that `origin` now has its `dev` pointing to `I2`.)

Now compare this graph to the one in the upstream Bitbucket repository, the one your Git calls `upstream`:

```
...--B--C--D   <-- master
            \
             N--O   <-- dev
```

The difference between these two graphs is that you will ask them—your `upstream`—to take your `origin`'s `H2` and `I2` and add those to their `dev` ... which is what you asked for in your question.

Note that your own (local) repository still has the complicated, tangled mess of branches named `zaphod` and so on.  Once your upstream has accepted your changes to their `dev`—taken your `H2` and `I2`—it's probably time to clean up your local repository, making it look at least a little bit, if not a lot, like your `origin` repository.  To do that, you can delete your own `zaphod` branch entirely:

```
                      H--I   [abandoned]
                     /
...--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- master
            \
             N--O   <-- upstream/dev (maybe)
                 \
                  H2--I2   <-- for-origin-dev, origin/dev, upstream/dev (maybe)
```

Note that once you drop a branch label, the only way to find the commits that you used to find from the branch label, is to use some other name (like the raw hash ID).  If *all* names for some commit(s) are gone, so that there is no way to find them, they will eventually be *garbage collected*, i.e., tossed out entirely.  This is what will happen to the original `H--I`, now that they are abandoned.

The `(maybe)`s above are because your own Git won't know that `upstream` has accepted your pull request until you run `git fetch upstream` to have your (local) Git call up the upstream Git and find its latest `dev`.